# Realizar download durante a instalação pelo Inno Setup

Tags: instalador, pascal, inno-setup

Trabalho em uma empresa que utiliza o Inno Setup para criar os instaladores dos seus produtos, recentemente fui incumbido da tarefa de criar uma instalador melhor, umas das melhorias que foram sugeridas seria realizar o download de um complemento durante o processo de instalação. Não estou muito familiarizado com este procedimento.

Gostaria de saber como insiro esta informação no arquivo que tenho os códigos do meu instalador.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o plugin [Inno Download Plugin](https://mitrichsoftware.wordpress.com/inno-setup-tools/inno-download-plugin/).

Exemplo de utilização:

```
#include <idp.iss>

[Files]
Source: "{tmp}\file1.xyz"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external; ExternalSize: 1048576
Source: "{tmp}\file2.xyz"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external; ExternalSize: 1048576
Source: "{tmp}\file3.xyz"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: external; ExternalSize: 1048576

[Icons]
Name: "{group}\{cm:UninstallProgram,My Program}"; Filename: "{uninstallexe}"

[Code]
procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
    idpAddFileSize('http://127.0.0.1/file1.xyz', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\file1.xyz'), 1048576);
    idpAddFileSize('http://127.0.0.1/file2.xyz', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\file2.xyz'), 1048576);
    idpAddFileSize('http://127.0.0.1/file3.xyz', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\file3.xyz'), 1048576);

    idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);
end.
```

Ou

O Plugin [InnoTools Downloader](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50), para utilização, consultar [Documentação](http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/innotools/itdhelp/index.html)

Comment: David boa tarde, como tenho certeza que estes plugins estão instalados na minha maquina realizei o download do Inno Download Plugin porem mesmo após a instalação não vejo nenhum mudança no software.

Answer (score 2):

Boa tarde,

Consegui realizar da seguinte forma, em [TASK], acrescentei uma opção para o cliente decidir se deseja realizar o download o ou não, depois de informar a minha base de dados acrescentei em [CODE] a seguinte condição.

```
function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin  
Result := True;
if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
begin
if WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[1] then
if MsgBox('O download pode demorar dependendo da velocidade da sua internet, deseja continuar ?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES then 
begin 
idpAddFile('http://www.site.com.br/download/teste.exe', ExpandConstant('{tmp}\teste.exe'));
idpDownloadAfter(wpReady);

end else
begin
if CurPageID = wpSelectTasks then
WizardForm.TasksList.Checked[1] := False;
end;
end;
end;
```